# Azure Serverless SQL server database backup/restore

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, serverless

I've created an azure **serverless ** sql database. It seems there is no way to backup/restore this type of databases. I know there is restore to a point in time feature, But I what to download and save database backups my self.

Is there a way to backup serverless azure sql databases?

1-) There is no Backup/restore option on the database right click
2-) I've tried to use BACKUP T-SQL with azure storage account and storage url from SSMS but this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the "export" functionality by accessing the specific database in your Azure Portal to get a copy of your DB.
2. You can rely on Azure SQL's integrated Backup funcionality by setting up your requirements by accessing your DB Server in you Azure Portal and selecting the "Backup" uption.
3. You can use SSMS (SQL Management Studio), right click on the DB in question, and select "Tasks" --> "Export Data-tier Application", which will return a .bacpac file with your database. *NOTE: bacpac files are not quite the same as full .bak files. bacpac files are not aware of any transactions that may be being executed whilst the data is being dumped, which means that you could end up with some data corruption.*

Answer (score 0):

Export your database as bacpac to an Storage Account. We are using weekly exports of the database on Saturdays, with a retention of one year for long-term backups.

The export will trigger an auto-resume of the database if the database was auto-paused.

We use an Azure Automation account and a PowerShell script to schedule the export of the database. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/manage/azure-automation-automated-export) you will find the script and the steps needed to schedule the script using Azure Automation.